# Is there a way to provide an external WSDL file to a Python Suds client

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds

I am working with a SOAP service where the project provides an external WSDL file.  I am using Python + Suds to connect to the service.  I run into issues because the (https) service URL looks like:

/sipxconfig/services/UserService?wsdl

But the WSDL ath that URL does *not* match the external WSDL file that is provided by the project.  The SOAP document returned *does* match the external WSDL file.  So my suds client raises a fault.

I have so far managed to work around this by writing a suds plugin to "correct" the SOAP XML returned so that it matches the dynamically created WSDL (at the URL).  However, I was hoping there was a way to feed the subs client the external WSDL file and then switch it to using the URL for the service.

I tried something like this:

```
wsdl_file = os.path.abspath(args.wsdl_file)
client = Client("file://%s" % wsdl_file, transport=t, username=sip_user, password=sip_pwd, doctor=doctor)
client.set_options(location=url)

#Get the results.
user_search = client.factory.create("UserSearch")
user_search.byUserName = args.find_user
user_search.byFuzzyUserNameOrAlias = args.fuzzy
user_search.byGroup = args.group

result = client.service.findUser(user_search)
#^^^
#Error here!
```

But it ultimately results in a `MethodNotFound` exception.
I run netstat in another terminal, and I can see that the client is not making a network connection to the external service.

Has anyone else managed to feed Suds WSDL from a file?

Thanks,
Carl

Comment: You can also set the location option when constructing the Client: `Client(..., location=url)`.  Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I determined I was on the correct track, but my SOAP service had multiple ports.  I needed to do the following:

```
wsdl_file = os.path.abspath(args.wsdl_file)
client = Client("file://%s" % wsdl_file, transport=t, username=sip_user, password=sip_pwd, doctor=doctor)
client.set_options(location=url)

#Get the results.
user_search = client.factory.create("UserSearch")
user_search.byUserName = args.find_user
user_search.byFuzzyUserNameOrAlias = args.fuzzy
user_search.byGroup = args.group

result = client.service['UserService'].findUser(user_search)
#                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# This was the missing bit that threw me off!
```

Thanks,
Carl